# Correct calling init function in Apple Swift 5 subclass in Cocoa application

Tags: swift, cocoa, subclass

I cannot figure out the correct format for calling the init function of NSTextField in a subclass called HyperlinkTextField.

```
class HyperlinkTextField: NSTextField {
    var url: String = ""

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(string: url)!)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {  
        super.init(coder: coder)  
        isBezeled = false
    }  

    init(string: String) {
        super.init(string: string) // error: must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'NSTextField'
        isBezeled = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

All classes inheriting from `NSControl` have two designated initializers

1. `init?(coder: NSCoder)`
2. `init(frame: NSRect)`

So you must call the latter

```
init(string: String) {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    self.stringValue = string
    isBezeled = false
}
```

Comment: Why would 'isBezeled = false' have no effect when called in init? Creating a new function to initialize variables works.